# Safe way to merge my branch

Tags: git

I have master branch
and I have xx1 branch with 3 commits ahead (changes in file A) and 5 commits behind master (changes in file B)
What is the safe way to merge xx1 branch to master branch ?
should I merge first master to xxx1 ?
or because files are different I can just merge my branch to master ?

Comment: Typically, it is strange to speak of an individual _file_ as being ahead or behind another branch, rather an entire _branch_ is ahead of behind.  Are you using a tool such as GitHub?

Comment: Yes I'm using Github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes. You can merge and there might not be any merge conflicts as you said the files are different.

However, you can also rebase, which is a better option in my opinion. Rebase will make sure that all the commits are maintained individually.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: do you mean I can merge xx1 to master without merging first master to xx1?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you cannot do that. However, that is not the best practice.