# Safest way to merge my branch into master branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I have a branch called `file_migration` and I wanted to merge it with the master branch. I only want the files I have updated/added to be merged into master branch. If other people have made changes to master branch that are not captured in my branch, I don't want my merge to affect other peoples' changes.

For example, let's say the master's branch contains only 2 folders: `folder_1` and `folder_2`. My `file_migration` branch contains changes I made to `folder_1`. I have NOT changed anything in `folder_2`, but someone else has made changes to `folder_2`. So `folder_2` in my branch will be older than `folder_2` in master. I want to make sure my merge to master branch only updates `folder_1` and should not affect `folder_2` in master branch (because `folder_2` in my branch is older than `folder_2` in master branch so I don't want my merge to affect `folder_2`).

What will be the best protocol to ensure I only apply my changes made to `folder_1` to master branch without changing anything in `folder_2`? I've read this other question [Safe way to merge my branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40398767/safe-way-to-merge-my-branch) where people suggest they can simply git merge to master branch. But I am not sure if the situation mentioned in that question applies to my case.

Comment: Judt merge it. If conflicts arise, you can decide what happens, anyways.

Comment: in general, git knows to handle it. are you using github or another web based git platform?

Comment: The command for doing this is `git merge <branch where you want to merge from>`, executed from the branch you want to merge to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge it.

Git is smart enough to know what was changed and what was not. It doesn't matter if your branch is out of date, if you did not change a file Git will not merge any change to the file. [You can read more about merge strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28version_control%29); Git uses several and will pick the most appropriate.

Don't worry if the merge goes wrong, as with many things in Git [you can undo it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet).

Comment: Thank you, @Schwern. It's good to know that when git merge to remote branch it will only merge files that I've updated in my branch. I still got a lot to learn about git, but this gives me the peace of mind.

Comment: @Stanleyrr Note that master is not a remote branch. It is a local branch which has a remote. That's important because nothing you do to master will affect anyone else until you push it. That's why is safe to experiment with your local master branch.

Comment: @Stanleyrr Git is genuinely hard, but very worth the effort to learn.

Comment: Btw @Schwern, is it okay if I do the merge by clicking the "Merge pull request" button in the Pull Request in github? (the PR has already been approved by my colleagues)

Comment: @Stanleyrr Yes, if it passed review it's fine to merge. In the future, before submitting your PR bring your branch up to date with a `git merge master` and make sure it still works with the latest changes.

Answer (score 1):

back merge master(commit and push the changes from master) to your `file_migration` branch. If their are any conflicts in folder 2, take the changes of master branch. and if their are any conflicts in folder 1, then resolve according to your need.

Now, try to merge the changes from `file_migration` branch to master. Ideally it will not show any changes in folder 2. But if it shows then, donnot stage the changes. Stage only relevant changes, and commit push.

Comment: Thanks, @Kushal. Could you elaborate what you meant by 'back merge'?

Comment: Back merge means, merging the parent branch to feature branch. So that if there are any conflicts, it can be resolved. So,  merge master to feature branch.

Comment: There's no point in merging from master and then immediately merging to master. Save a merge and merge straight to master. If it goes wrong, undo it.

Comment: I have suggested the back merge because, if there are any conflicts in folder2 then we can take the master version. and yeah, if you not not made any changes then anyways it will not show any commit changes

Answer (score 1):

The safest way to merge using Github is a pull request from your branch to master. You can read more here https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

Comment: I have already submitted a pull request (PR) and my appears have approved it. You mentioned git knows how to handle the difference. Does that mean if git notices data in a folder in master branch are ahead of my commits, it will preserve those data even if my branch contains older data for that folder?

Comment: Note that if you're submitting a branch as a PR you should bring it up to date by merging master into your branch before submitting it. This allows you to resolve conflicts and test that it works with the latest changes in master. It means less work for the reviewers.